# SVG Text Rendering on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

A newbie question. SVG text fill seems not to fill the text in Chrome (same problem in Chrome Canary). Firefox and IE work well. Could someone point me to a work-around, perhaps? Here's the HTML/SVG document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>SVG Text</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>
      Text Example
   </h2>
   <svg id="svgText" height="250" width="600">
      <text id="txt" x="100" y="250" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="200" font-weight="bolder" 
         stroke="red" fill="red">TEXT</text>
   </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!!

[Please see screen-shot below (Google Chrome on Win7). Note the edges of X as well as the right edge of the first T.]
[image: Note the edges of X as well as the right edge of the first T. Screenshot taken on Google Chrome on Win7]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? This file looks fine for me in Chrome. The text is filled with red as I would expect.

Comment: Hi  Paul LeBeau - I have added a screenshot of what I see on Chrome when preview the above HTML snippet on Win7. I wonder if there is an OS difference?

Comment: Looks like you disabled font smoothing. Re-enabling it might make the problem go away. (Go to the control panel, search for "cleartype", and click on "Adjust ClearType". Make sure "Turn on ClearType" is checked.)

Comment: ClearType was turned off, and turning it on made those lines shift but not disappear. Both Firefox and IE render the text absolutely as expected - why would Chrome depend on ClearType while the other two browsers apparently do not?

Comment: I also see mis-fills on Chrome latest (Win 8.1) but in my case, the bad fill is  a thin line inside the left edge of the text. My clear type is turned on.

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes with clear type on, that's exactly what I see. Cheers!

Comment: Safari on MacOS and iOS render the text correctly. So does Chrome on iOS. Could be a Chrome on Windows issue, perhaps? Is there a workaround for Chrome on Windows, though?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 41 on Windows and am not seeing the effect that you are.  Everything looks fine.

Comment: For reference, this was reported as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478384.

Comment: Hi Erik, yes, I have reported it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

OK, it appears to be a Chrome bug (on Windows). I have reported it here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478384

Thank you all for the comments! Much appreciated.